# How to add rows that is grouped by a new group in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Update: This is a different question to the previous one, when I use ROLLUP in this question, it will add a total row, but I only want a group C to combine group A and B, thus group C shows the subtotal of color X, Y and Z. No total row needed.

I have data like this

```
Group Color Money
A     X     100
A     X     300
A     Y     200
B     X     200
B     Y     300
B     Y     100
B     Z     110
```

I want to make a new Group C that contains A&B

Is there anyway to query out data in mysql like this?

```
Group Color SumMoney AvgMoney DataCount
A     X     400      200      2
A     Y     200      200      1
B     X     200      200      1
B     Y     400      200      2    
B     Z     110      110      1
C     X     600      200      3
C     Y     600      200      3
C     Z     110      110      1
```

I think UNION may solve the problem but it may also be slow and the syntax would be long(harder to maintain(not in this case)). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Very similar to your post a few hours ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981520/how-to-use-group-by-to-count-a-new-category-and-old-categories-at-once.

Comment: Similar answer as an hours ago, but `GROUPING SETS` instead of `ROLLUP`

Comment: You did not even accept answer to your previous question and you are already reposting it. Use the union and if it gets slow post a new question about improving the query speed. "Syntax would be long" is pointless statement in SQL. Length of query does not have direct impact on execution speed. Sometimes long query can be the only one that works as well as the fastest for a task. Also if you change your mind about something you can edit a question (which is what this question should have been)

Comment: I know it's somewhat similar, but these are two different questions, not reposting. ROLLUP is good for the previous question. But in this case, there will be one more row showing total, not just only subtotal. Thanks for dnoeth answering my question. Now I know I should use GROUPING SETS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    g.`group`,
    g.color,
    sum(g.money) AS SumMoney,
    CAST(AVG(g.money) AS SIGNED) AS AvgMoney,
    COUNT(g.`group`) AS DataCount
FROM
    groups g
GROUP BY
    g.`group`,
    g.color

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'C',
    g.color,
    sum(g.money) AS SumMoney,
    CAST(AVG(g.money) AS SIGNED) AS AvgMoney,
    COUNT(g.`group`) AS DataCount
FROM
    groups g
GROUP BY
    g.color
```

Output is:

```
group | color | SumMoney | AvgMoney | DataCount
-----------------------------------------------
A     | X     |      400 |      200 |        2
A     | Y     |      200 |      200 |        1
B     | X     |      200 |      200 |        1
B     | Y     |      400 |      200 |        2
B     | Z     |      110 |      110 |        1
C     | X     |      600 |      200 |        3
C     | Y     |      600 |      200 |        3
C     | Z     |      110 |      110 |        1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select group,color,sum(money) as SumMoney ,avg(money) as AvgMoney,
       count(*) as DataCount from table_name group by group,color
```